# How to order by weight using sphinxQL foolcode

Tags: php, sphinx

I am using the following query

```
$results = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select()
    ->from('rt')
    ->match('',$searchText,true)
    ->where('CategoryID',$CatFilter,(int)$CategoryID)          
    ->orderBy('Level','DESC')          
    ->limit($start, $number)      
    ->enqueue(SphinxQL::create($conn)->query('SHOW META'))
    ->executeBatch();
```

It sorts the result by Level and don't consider other fields if the level is same. I want to sort the same level by `WEIGHT()`

How can I get the `weight()` function in foolcode?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this easily

```
  $results = SphinxQL::create($conn)
             ->query($sql)     
             ->executeBatch();
```